# Steps to create a edge node for aws emr

Tags: amazon-ec2, emr

I have a requirement to create an edge node (ec2) for an AWS EMR cluster. Is there a list of steps that I can follow to make this happen?

Answer (score 4):

Run the below commands as root on your EC2-Instance(Edge Node)

```
mkdir -p /usr/lib/spark
mkdir -p /usr/lib/hive-webhcat/share/hcatalog
vi  /etc/profile.d/spark.sh
    export SPARK_HOME=/usr/lib/spark
    export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
    export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf
export SPARK_CONF_DIR=/etc/spark/conf

source /etc/profile.d/spark.sh
mkdir -p /etc/hadoop/conf
chown -R kylo:kylo /etc/hadoop/conf
mkdir -p /etc/spark/conf
chown -R kylo:kylo /etc/spark/conf
mkdir -p /usr/share/aws /usr/lib/sqoop /usr/lib/hadoop-yarn /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce /usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs /usr/lib/hadoop
chown kylo:kylo /usr/share/aws /usr/lib/sqoop /usr/lib/hadoop-yarn /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce /usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs /usr/lib/hadoop

export MASTER_PRIVATE_IP=<MASTER_NODE_IP_ADDRESS>
export PEM_FILE=/home/centos/.ssh/id_rsa
scp -i $PEM_FILE hadoop@$MASTER_PRIVATE_IP:/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml /etc/hadoop/conf
scp -i $PEM_FILE hadoop@$MASTER_PRIVATE_IP:/etc/hadoop/conf/yarn-site.xml /etc/hadoop/conf
scp -i $PEM_FILE hadoop@$MASTER_PRIVATE_IP:/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml /etc/hadoop/conf
scp -i $PEM_FILE hadoop@$MASTER_PRIVATE_IP:/etc/hadoop/conf/mapred-site.xml /etc/hadoop/conf

rsync -avz --delete -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ServerAliveInterval=10 -i $PEM_FILE" hadoop@$MASTER_PRIVATE_IP:'/usr/lib/spark/*' /usr/lib/spark
rsync -avz --delete -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ServerAliveInterval=10 -i $PEM_FILE" hadoop@$MASTER_PRIVATE_IP:'/usr/lib/sqoop/*' /usr/lib/sqoop
rsync -avz --delete -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ServerAliveInterval=10 -i $PEM_FILE" hadoop@$MASTER_PRIVATE_IP:'/usr/lib/hadoop/*' /usr/lib/hadoop
rsync -avz --delete -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ServerAliveInterval=10 -i $PEM_FILE" hadoop@$MASTER_PRIVATE_IP:'/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/*' /usr/lib/hadoop-yarn
rsync -avz --delete -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ServerAliveInterval=10 -i $PEM_FILE" hadoop@$MASTER_PRIVATE_IP:'/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/*' /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce
rsync -avz --delete -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ServerAliveInterval=10 -i $PEM_FILE" hadoop@$MASTER_PRIVATE_IP:'/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/*' /usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs
rsync -avz --delete -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ServerAliveInterval=10 -i $PEM_FILE" hadoop@$MASTER_PRIVATE_IP:'/usr/share/aws/*' /usr/share/aws

rsync -avz --delete -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ServerAliveInterval=10 -i $PEM_FILE" hadoop@$MASTER_PRIVATE_IP:'/etc/spark/conf/*' /etc/spark/conf

echo "spark.hadoop.yarn.timeline-service.enabled false" >> /etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
```

You might need to ls for this file on the master node since the version could be different

```
scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ServerAliveInterval=10 -i $PEM_FILE hadoop@$MASTER_PRIVATE_IP:/usr/lib/hive-hcatalog/share/hcatalog/hive-hcatalog-core-2.3.3-amzn-1.jar /usr/lib/hive-webhcat/share/hcatalog/hive-hcatalog-core.jar
```

You should ls to verify the JAR path

```
ls /usr/lib/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_ <HIT TAB>
spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --master yarn --driver-memory 512m --executor-memory 512m --executor-cores 1 /usr/lib/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.1.jar 10
```

Check the Yarn UI to verify it was successful

```
http://<MASTER_NODE>:8088/cluster
```

Comment: @mbreddy77, if the answer works..you may mark it as correct so other engineer will also use it. If you got question please comment...

Comment: @FaisalAhmedSiddiqui: No,  You can write a CF to create EC2 and execute the shell script on bootstrap with these commands.

Comment: I followed the steps and also setup
 HADOOP_YARN_HOME
and HADOOP_ MAPRED_HOME
environment variables but hadoop streaming job failed with error &quot;file not found&quot;. However same thing working fine if run streaming job from master node.. Any thoughts??

Comment: @FaisalAhmedSiddiqui: can paste the error from log file.

Comment: there were couple of things that i was missing while setting up edge node for my EMR cluster versino 5.20. 
Missing HADOOP_YARN_HOME and HDOOP_MAPRED_HOME in spark.sh
and also missing the lzo native installation that i did using 
yum install lzo liblzo-devel
also added YARN_HOME environment variable to view yarn logs file from edge node.